Error: PHP extension required: "pdo_sqlite" after installing Kanboard
After I installed Kanboard on a Ubuntu 18 server and try to open it in the browser I see:

Internal Error: PHP extension required: "pdo_sqlite"

PHP is 7.4. When I try sudo apt-get install php7.4-sqlite3 I get:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-sqlite3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-sqlite3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-sqlite3'

I want to install php7.4-sqlite3 on the server. There are PHP versions 7.2, 7.4 and 8.1 installed. When I run sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3 I get:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-sqlite3 is already the newest version (1:7.2+60ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1086 linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1088
  linux-headers-5.4.0-1088-aws linux-image-5.4.0-1088-aws
  linux-modules-5.4.0-1088-aws
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.

When I check PHP info using php -i | grep 'sqlite' I get nothing and the error remains. When I check PHP info for each version and if pdo_sqlite is installed for PHP7.2 by php7.2 -i | grep 'sqlite'I get:
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite
pdo_sqlite
sqlite3
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value


"the php is 7.4" - why? Keep in mind that this version is EOL since the end of 2022

you can manually install php extension and edit php.ini file. or rebuild php with extensions

"pdo_sqlite has been installed for PHP7.2" - that doesn't mean anything if you're not using PHP 7.2. Keep in mind that you try to use an unsupported version of PHP on an unsupported version of Ubuntu. It's not a surprise that this causes a lot of trouble
